# .NET Core 1.0.0 POST FromBody request is always null.

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My new POST endpoint is always getting null for the request, and I can't figure out why.

```
// api/StudentQueue/Comment
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Comment")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostStudentComment([FromBody]StudentQueueNewCommentModel model)
    {
        // stuff
    }
```

Here's that model:

```
public class StudentQueueNewCommentModel
{
    public StudentQueueCommentModel Comment { get; set; }
    public StudentQueueModel Student{ get; set; }
}
```

And here's my payload:

```
{
  "Comment": {
    "ActionId": 2,
    "ActionName": "Contacted – Student Responded",
    "Comment": "jhgfd",
    "CreatedDate": "Thu Jan 26 2017 11:14:17 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)",
    "CreatorName": "TODO: Figure this out"
  },
  "Student": {
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Inquisitive",
    "Lastname": "Seal",
    "Email": "iseal@mailinator.com",
    "PhoneNumber": "(555) 555-5555",
    "Comments": [
      {
        "createdDate": "2016-10-19T00:00:00",
        "comment": "Comment 1",
        "actionId": 1,
        "actionName": "Contacted – Waiting for Response",
        "creatorName": "Bobby Ross"
      },
      {
        "createdDate": "2016-10-19T00:00:00",
        "comment": "Comment 2",
        "actionId": 2,
        "actionName": "Contacted – Student Responded",
        "creatorName": "Lil Drop Tables"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have `content-type`:`application/json`, but I have a breakpoint set in the first line of the API method, and it's null without fail, every single time.

I tried wrapping my payload in a `{model: everythingabove}` which in the controller gives me a model object with `Student` and `Comment` being null.  I'm totally at a loss for what's happening here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It didn't like my Date format (reasonably of course).  I ended up not sending the Date because I want it to be set server-side anyway.

Comment: Hope you found it from the model state error collection

Comment: I... don't know how to view that.  I didn't have anything blatantly obvious to me that that was happening.  I just went through Postman and started removing stuff until it started to show up